# Bootstrap modal + readFile: how force file download?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where the user click on the "DOWNLOAD" button.
This opens a modal, that requires a CODE to authorize the download.

Once inserted, the CODE is ajax-submitted to a PHP script that validate the code and recover a file OUTSIDE webroot and need to force the download.

But, I see in Firebug that script "echoes" the file content...

I need to "close" the modal and force the download. Thank you very much!

HTML (modal)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="downloadpayroll" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="downloadpayrolllabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modal-form-container">
            <form method="post" class="form" id="enable-payroll-download" action="{{ @ABSOLUTE_PATH }}{{ @ALIASES.url_payroll_new }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="payroll_id" value="" />
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Conferma download</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Per confermare il download, <strong>inserisci il tuo PIN</strong></p>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pin">PIN</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center required-field numbers-only" name="pin" />
                        </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Scarica cedolino</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY submit

```
var data = $form.serialize();
            data = data+'&ajax=true';
            $.ajax({
                    data    : data,
                    type    : $form.attr('method'),
                    url     : $form.attr('action'),
                    success : function(response) {
                        // nothing to do here
                    } // success
            });
```

PHP script

```
// other stuffssss
if ($validate===true) {
                // IL PIN E' CORRETTO, TIRIAMO FUORI IL CEDOLINO
                $payroll = $this->service->getPayroll($id_payroll,'id',null,'ASC',1);
                $path = \SupportText::removeSubstringFromString($this->f3->get('SERVER.DOCUMENT_ROOT'), '/httpdocs').'/private';
                $filename = $path.'/'.$this->id_user.'/'.$payroll[0]->filename;
                \SupportFile::returnFile($filename);
                exit;
            }
```

PHP SupportFile class

```
class SupportFile {

    public static function returnFile( $filename ) {
        // Check if file exists, if it is not here return false:
        if ( !file_exists( $filename )) return false;
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        // Suggest better filename for browser to use when saving file:
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        // Caching headers:
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        // This should be set:
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
        // Clean output buffer without sending it, alternatively you can do ob_end_clean(); to also turn off buffering.
        ob_clean();
        // And flush buffers, don't know actually why but php manual seems recommending it:
        flush();
        // Read file and output it's contents:
        readfile( $filename );
        // You need to exit after that or at least make sure that anything other is not echoed out:
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: better create some temp routes for your files and then redirect to that when ajax is finished for the file donload

Comment: @madalinivascu tried with the temp route. Works. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ob_start (); before the header (). Then use the code as below

```
class SupportFile {

 public static function returnFile( $filename ) {
    if ( !file_exists( $filename )) return false;

    ob_strat();

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
    header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filename));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    ob_end_clean(); 
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $filename );
    exit;
  }
}
```